# Generate missing serialVersionUID for Groovy class

Tags: groovy

I'm well aware IntelliJ has the functionality built in for Java classes. There also exists a plugin that can do it as well. However, none of these options seem to work on Groovy classes.

I know Groovy imports `java.io.*` by default so the following is valid:

```
class User implements Serializable {

}
```

I can get around it by changing the file extension to `.java` which will then force IntelliJ to complain about the missing `serialVersionUID` and then change it back to `.groovy`, but that's just...wrong.

I can't get IntelliJ to generate the missing `serialVersionUID` for Groovy classes. Is there a way to generate the missing `serialVersionUID`? Working on a Grails 3 project so it's for a domain/Groovy class.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use Java serialisation... ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates I'm not sure what you're getting at. Is there an alternative?